# Form validation error message not working

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, field, required

I previously had some custom code added to my shopping cart which worked beautifly.  At some point, the error message that displays when the required field was not filled out, stopped working.

Here is the code: (revised with HTML included)

```
{% assign choices = "Other, Affiliate, Returning Customer, Practitioner, Dr. Ulan, Dr. Shallenberger, Dr. Dennis Courtney, WBAI - Take Charge of your Health Radio, Chek Institue, BodyHealth Newsletter, Yasmine Marca, Ben Greenfield, Steve Ilg, Tawnee Prazak, ABC4U, Natural Awakenings, Email Advertisment, Facebook, Twitter, Google, Forum, Friend, Letter, Optimum Healt Report, Townsend Letter, Autism Avenue" %}
{% assign required = true %}

<div class="form-vertical">
<p>
<select style="margin-left: 0px;" class="six columns" id="how-did-you-hear-about-us" name="attributes[how-did-you-hear-about-us]" >
<option value=""{% if cart.attributes.how-did-you-hear-about-us == "" %} selected{% endif %}>Please make a selection</option>
{% assign optionsArray = choices | split: ',' %}
{% for o in optionsArray %}
{% assign option = o | strip %}
<option value="{{ option }}"{% if cart.attributes.how-did-you-hear-about-us == option %} selected{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
{% endfor %}
<option value="Other"{% if cart.attributes.how-did-you-hear-about-us == "Other" %} selected{% endif %}>Other</option>
</select>
</p>
<p style="{% unless cart.attributes.how-did-you-hear-about-us == 'Other' %}display:none;{% endunless %}">
<label style="text-align: left;" class="three columns mobile_left alpha" for="how-did-you-hear-about-us-other">Where?:</label>
<input class="six columns" id="how-did-you-hear-about-us-other" type="text" name="attributes[how-did-you-hear-about-us-other]" value="{{ cart.attributes.how-did-you-hear-about-us-other }}" />
</p>
<p style="{% unless cart.attributes.how-did-you-hear-about-us == 'Affiliate' %}display:none;{% endunless %}">
<label style="text-align: left;" class="three columns mobile_left alpha" for="how-did-you-hear-about-us-affiliate">Who?:</label>
<input class="six columns" id="how-did-you-hear-about-us-affiliate" type="text" name="attributes[how-did-you-hear-about-us-affiliate]" value="{{ cart.attributes.how-did-you-hear-about-us-affiliate }}" />
</p>
</div>


<script>
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#how-did-you-hear-about-us').change(function() {
    if ($('#how-did-you-hear-about-us').val() == 'Other') {
      $('#how-did-you-hear-about-us-other').parent('p').show();
    } else {
      $('#how-did-you-hear-about-us-other').val('').parent('p').hide();
    }
  });
    $('#how-did-you-hear-about-us').change(function() {
    if ($('#how-did-you-hear-about-us').val() == 'Affiliate') {
      $('#how-did-you-hear-about-us-affiliate').parent('p').show();
    } else {
      $('#how-did-you-hear-about-us-affiliate').val('').parent('p').hide();
    }
  });
  {% if required %}
  $('input[name="checkout"], input[name="goto_pp"], input[name="goto_gc"]').click(function() {
    var validated = true;
    if ($('#how-did-you-hear-about-us').val() == '') {
      validated = false;    
    }
    else if ($('#how-did-you-hear-about-us').val() == 'Affiliate') {
      if ($('#how-did-you-hear-about-us-affiliate').val() == '') {
        validated = false; 
        $('#how-did-you-hear-about-us-affiliate').addClass('error');
      } 
    }
    if(validated){
      $(this).submit();
    }
    else{
      alert("Please tell us how you heard about us.");
      return false;
    }
  });
  {% endif %}
});
</script>
```

I'm using a Shopify store if that matters.  Furthermore, I wouldn't mind making a flyout or popup message to make it stand out more.

Currently I'm receiving no error message at all, just nothing happens.  However, people cannot click Checkout as they don't realize this is a required field.  So they think the site is broken.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: what are the errors you getting currently

Comment: please post ur html as well. It's very difficult to guess

Comment: Hello, sorry.  We stopped using this feature for a time but now have re-implemented.  I'm still running into this issue above.  Would appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: provide a fiddle or post your html

Comment: when the input `#how-did-you-hear-about-us` is an empty string your code just does nothing, didn't you forget to add an error class to the input like you do in the second `if` or something to show it is required?. Btw that's on the first `if` in the validation function.